# Mixing typescript definition files with nodejs require over multiple files in an internal module

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, typescript, npm, definitelytyped

Are there any known issues with mixing nodejs modules (require) with typescript definition files (d.ts) multiple times over files within a module?

My scenario is that I have a module namespace per folder (much like I would in C#), then I basically compile them all via tsc to an outputted `my-module.js`. However I keep getting really odd errors like `Could not find type HTMLElement` but lots of people have pointed out that tsc includes the typescript lib file by default which contains all those types.

I have noticed a few people having *odd* errors when they are including the same d.ts files over multiple files which are all compiled with the `--out` flag to get it all into one file, so could this be causing my issues?

An example of my usage would be:

```
///<reference path="path/to/knockout.d.ts" />
import ko = require("knockout");
```

This would then be put in each file which requires knockout js, which is at least 10 files in the module i'm trying to compile currently. It just bombs out constantly saying knockout.d.ts cannot find the type HTMLElemet, Element, Document etc.

Comment: I haven't had this problem - but maybe I'm below the threshold of the number of files it takes to show the problem. I have the references repeated a few times - but probably not as much as you. Ryan Cavanaugh may be best placed to answer this question.

Comment: it may be a red herring, but there are no errors logged against the files to be compiled it just errors on the `knockout.d.ts` however I am not sure how to best progress with the issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using external modules (which you are if you have a top level "import" - as shown above), then you can't use the --out switch to combine multiple source files.  It is a limitation that with external modules that one source file = one module.  With source that is not in an external module (i.e. contributes to the 'global' scope), you can combine input source to one output JavaScript file using --out.

I have no idea about the "could not find HTMLElement" issues.  If you can provide a repro (and outline which version you are using) I can take a look.

Comment: the `import ko = require("knockout");` is me trying to require a non typescript module via npm. (`npm install knockout`). I include the definition file for ko above in the reference. It is a more complicated use case but I believe it should be legit. There may be nothing wrong with the imports above etc, but the compiler just complains that it cannot find the types in knockout.d.ts which I cannot believe.